# How to connect Php to monetdb server

Tags: php, database, connection, monetdb

I am new in monetdb database server.Currently I try to connect Php to Monetdb server.But I can not find any tutorial/documentation about it.
I found simple script in following url
https://gist.github.com/maimai-swap/5432188
But where i find php_monetdb.php file? 
 In short, How can I connect php to monetdb? is there any proper documentaion.
Someone can help me with this? Thank you everyone!!

Comment: Documentation like this: https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation?

Comment: no.Because in this documentation no where mention properly How can i connect php to monetdb.And what step should follow for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best to download this file directly from the mercurial repository at the moment. It contains some minor bugfixes that you might wish to have. You can do this at the following url:

https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB/file/tip/clients/php/lib

In the repository you can also find an example script on how to use MonetDB with PHP. This can be found here:

https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB/file/tip/clients/php/examples/query.php